# Linking to other html pages using <a> tags in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-template

So I'm very new to Angular 2 and I'm using it to make a personal website. I have a main page with bio information on it and another page where I'll have blog content inside it. Both these pages will have the same header and footer with simply different body content inside them. The project file directory looks a bit like this, with footer, header and blog being components.

```
app
├── app.component.html
├── app.module.ts
├── app.component.ts
├── app.component.spec.ts
├── blog
|   ├── blog.component.html
|   └── blog.component.spec.ts
|   └── blog.component.ts  
├── footer
|   ├── footer.component.html
|   └── footer.component.spec.ts
|   └── footer.component.ts
├── header
|   ├── header.component.html
|   └── header.component.spec.ts
|   └── header.component.ts
```

For simplicity, I've taken out irrelevant files and CSS from the above example.

Now in my header (header.component.html) - I have the following code which intends to allow users to navigate from the home page to blog page and back

```
<!-- Header -->
<div class="header container-fluid">
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Logo">
 </div>
<div class="col-md-6 offset-6">
 <a href="../../index.html">Home</a>
 <a href="../blog/blog.component.html">Blog</a>
</div>
```

However, the blog.component.html page won't link. I don't understand how links are supposed to work in Angular 2- should I create another html page where the blog is linked through it's selector or what? I feel like this is a stupid question and I'm sure there's an obvious answer- I just can't seem to crack it though! I've read stuff about 'routing' on other pages, although they seem to be pedaling solutions that seem so complicated when traditional html and JS seem to link up html pages through a tags so easily!

What am I doing wrong? Please someone give me help here- I would love a simple and easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly, you need to go and create a router for your application. You can find a how to [here](https://angular.io/guide/router).

It'll probably look something like this for your app (the below goes inside `app.module`):

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent},
  { path: '',
   redirectTo: '/blog',
   pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes
    )
    // other imports here
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then you need to implement the `[routerLink]` property instead of using hrefs. `routerLink` is like href for angular, except it keeps the routing internal and emulates a real `window.location` change.

```
<!-- Header -->
<div class="header container-fluid">
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Logo">
 </div>
<div class="col-md-6 offset-6">
 <a routerLink="../../index.html">Home</a>
 <a routerLink="../blog/blog.component.html">Blog</a>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: So in the bottom with the <a routerLink> tags, do we put in the relative links as normal? I tried using the relative links and they wouldn't get me to my page

Comment: @RobbiePeck As far as I am aware, and according to that tutorial linked above, yes you can use relative paths. Maybe double check the tutorial...

Comment: @RobbiePeck please see the update, I forgot to include `<router-outlet>` and also, the default component should not be AppComponent, it should be BlogComponent in your case... as now shown in the answer.